# linear independence of finite binary sequences

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra

Let $V_n=\{-1,1\}^n$ be the hypercube and let $C_n$ be a collection 
$\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ of $n$ distinct elements of $V_n.$

Question: what is the smallest number $N(n)$ of non-zero vectors with integer coefficients are needed to check that $C_n$ is linearly independent over the integers? That is, what is the smallest set of such vectors $\{v_1,...v_{N(n)}\}$ that if $C_n$ is linearly dependent over the integers then there exists some element $v_{i}$ with coordinates $(k_1,...,k_n)$ such that $k_1x_1+...+k_nx_n$ is zero.

Comment: Do you mean "zero" at the end?

Comment: Do you really want your collection of vectors `$\{x_1,\ldots, x_n\}$' to be unordered?  

Comment: Siegel's lemma will give you an estimate.

Comment: Yes, I did mean "zero" at the end.

Answer (score 1):

A natural idea would be to take all vectors from $[-t,t]^n$ for some $t$. The optimal value of such a $t$ is roughly $n^{n/2}$. This follows from results in this paper: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-011-0474-y.

Can anyone give a better upper bound than $N\le n^{n^2/2}$?

Comment: I would like to see a set C that is linearly dependent and yet has all 3^n quantities v*C nonzero. Here v ranges over vectors whose coordinates are -1 or 1 or 0.   Gerhard "Maybe We Can Do Better" Paseman, 2018.12.05.